# margin auto not working after vertical aligning

Tags: css

I know `margin:0 auto;` will center a div horizontal but I also want to center it vertically so I used this

```
vertical-align:middle;
top:50%;
transform:translate Y(-50%);
```

But when I run this code the div is centered vertically but it doesn't center horizontally. Please can someone give me a better clue on how to center a div both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Did you add position: relative; to it?

Comment: Yes I did added a relative position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center both vertically and horizontally following your attempt, try this:

```
// assumed positioned element
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

[Reference](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#hv3), and another good [resource](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

Answer (score 2):

`Flex` has become extremely popular, I would recommend that because of its other capabilities.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ne38nx7t/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="Aligner">
   <div class="Aligner-item">Apples</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Aligner {
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid blue;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[Flex Vertical](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your entire code feel free to post your code on to a fiddle, till then check the following fiddle I created to, center content horizontally and vertically, where in the content has a dynamic height

http://jsfiddle.net/Q92Lb/2/

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#page{display:table;overflow:hidden;margin:0px auto;}
*:first-child+html #page {position:relative;}/*ie7*/
* html #page{position:relative;}/*ie6*/

#content_container{display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;}
*:first-child+html #content_container{position:absolute;top:50%;}/*ie7*/
* html #content_container{position:absolute;top:50%;}/*ie6*/

*:first-child+html #content{position:relative;top:-50%;}/*ie7*/
* html #content{position:relative;top:-50%;}/*ie6*/

html,body{height:100%;}
#page{height:100%;width:465px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
       <div id="content_container">
               <div id="content">
                     <p>your content</p>
               </div>
       </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```